# Unable to Bypass Error When File is Not There

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to read the "Data.csv" file within each Test folder.
There are multiple folders with the name "Test" (Test1, Test2, Test3, etc). These Test folders have an archived zip file named "ArchivedFiles.zip" where the Data.csv is in.
However, if one of the Test folders does not have the "Data.csv" file, I am unable to have this code work. I want to be able to move on if there is no Data.csv within the archived folder. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Here is how I am trying to handle it:

```
for x in Test:
    print(f"{x}:")
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(x + '/ArchivedFiles.zip')
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(zf.open('Data.csv'))
        df_filter= df[['Time','Name',"Type", "Status", "Counters"]]
        testFilter = df_filter[(df_filter.Type == 'Test')]
        if testFilter['Status'].str.contains('Fail').any():
            finalTable= testFilter[(testFilter.Status == 'Fail')]
            if finalTable.empty:
                print("Table Empty")
            else:
                fullFinalTable= finalTable[['Time','Name', "Counters"]]
                finalTableFilter = fullFinalTable.to_string()
                print(finalTableFilter)
        else:
            print("No Fails")
    except OSError:
        pass
```

This is the error message I get

```
line 508, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(zf.open('Data.csv'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\zipfile.py", line 1352, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\zipfile.py", line 1281, in getinfo
    'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
KeyError: "There is no item named 'Data.csv' in the archive"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `KeyError` instead of `OSError`. Use-

```
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting  KeyError so catch that:

```
except KeyError:
  pass
```

Best is catch all errors:

```
except:
  pass
```

Also, you will get boolean value with this:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists('data.csv')
```